# Roots of polynomial equation $x^6+2x^5+4x^4+8x^3+16x^2+32x+64=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

> If $x_1,x_2,...,x_6$ be the roots of $x^6+2x^5+4x^4+8x^3+16x^2+32x+64=0$ then I have to show that $|x_j|=2\space\space\space\forall j\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$

I get that the roots of the equation must be complex, of the form $a+ib$ where $|a+ib|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=2$ for all $|x_i|$. I don't get how to find the value of $a+ib$. How do I find the roots?

Comment: If you let $x=2z$ you can remove a factor of $64$ from each term.

Comment: @lulu What is $z$?

Comment: $z=\frac x2$.  It's just a change of variables.

Comment: [Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E6%2B2x%5E5%2B4x%5E4%2B8x%5E3%2B16x%5E2%2B32x%2B64%3D0) is what Wolfram Alpha has about the equation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Hint:**\begin{multline}x^6+2x^5+4x^4+8x^3+16x^2+32x+64=\\=64\left(\left(\frac x2\right)^6+\left(\frac x2\right)^5+\left(\frac x2\right)^4+\left(\frac x2\right)^3+\left(\frac x2\right)^2+\frac x2+1\right).\end{multline}Also, use the fact that $x^7-1=(x-1)(x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)$.

Comment: I can't proceed ;-(

Comment: Now use the fact that$$x^7-1=(x-1)(x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1).$$

Comment: So, we have $\frac{(x/2)^7-1}{(x/2)-1}=0$ and $x\neq 2$. Right??

Comment: Right, but what matters really is that $\left(\frac x2\right)^7=1$.

Comment: So, then, $x=(2^7)^{1/7}$ will give some complex solution. Right?

Comment: I *strongly* suggest that you avoid fractional exponents when dealing with complex non-real numbers. What happens is that$$\left(\frac x2\right)^7=1\implies\left\lvert\frac x2\right\rvert^7=1\iff\left\lvert\frac x2\right\rvert=1\iff\lvert x\rvert=2.$$

Comment: Thanks for your advice ;-)

Answer (score 3):

$$x^6+2x^5+4x^4+8x^3+16x^2+32x+64=0$$
Let $z=x/2$, so
$$z^6+z^5+z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1=0$$
from $z \neq 1$ 
Then $\frac{1-z^7}{1-z}=0 $
so $1-z^7=0$
so $z$ is the $n$ th root of $7$.
from $x=2z$ ,so $|x|=|2z|$ so $|x|=|2z|=2$

Comment: oh its have already solved. sorry